# Windows login using C#

Tags: c#, .net, nfc, proximity, winlogon

I have a C# application which reads my NFC tag and gets the ID of it.

Using NFC proximity API's, I was able to read a NFC tag.

When subscribed to NFC Tag arrival,

```
proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += (device) => {Print(device.DeviceId);};
```

corresponding `Device-ID`

```
\\?\aci#nxp54442#2&daba3ff&2#(fb3842cd-blah blah blah)
```

***How to make this application run at windows login so that when I tap my NFC tag, the application reads the tag and auto-logins the user ?***

Comment: I believe this is not supported. In Windows XP / 2003 you could have done it using a custom GINA, but this support was removed in Vista because it led to rampant security problems -- custom GINAs often were lax with users' secrets (passwords) and would cause people to get screwed. Windows 8 has some sort of logon provider mechanism but I'm not sure if there are easy ways for you to interact with it that way.

Comment: (To clarify, my previous comment is talking about the act of logging a user in, not about running code when no interactive user is logged on)

Comment: @BillyONeal: applications like http://www.sensiblevision.com/en-us/fastaccessanywhere/overview.aspx does similar to what I am trying to do. Any pointers to do similar kind of things?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx <-- I believe it uses this facility.

Comment: In particular, as with other OS hooks and plugins, I'm not sure you can use the CLR (and thus C#) even with this interface. Your UI can be written in C#, but anything that goes into the address space of a system process can't load the CLR into that process. This is because different versions of the CLR conflict and can't be loaded together -- so if Plugin A tries to load .NET 2.0's CLR, and Plugin B tries to load .NET 4.0's CLR, then the second load will always fail. The shell explicitly bans using .NET to implement shell extensions; I'm not sure if it applies to LogonUI.

Comment: @BillyONeal: thanks Billy. Am exploring ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two option, I know what kind of this application is exactly. But if you want to run the application at windows start up you can either look option for Windows Service or keep the application at start up location if it is simple EXE. This will run when windows will start up. In case of Windows server you have to make start up type 'Automatic'

Comment: When I make a service `run at startup`, basically `it runs after somebody logs in to the computer`. But, the question is `how to run an application even before somebody logs on`.

Comment: @now: No, that's not true. If you make a Windows Service have automatic start, it starts before the user logs in. However, that's not your big issue here; the big issue is your desire to take over the console and log a user on interactively, which I believe is unsupported.